# Getting lots of NXDOMAIN response

Tags: dns

Currently I am analyzing the DNS logs from various Windows servers. I am seeing lots of **NXDOMAIN** response from the DNS server. When I looked into the query field, it is something like 'NHCNEBDBEBEEBFEDCDCDFDBDEDEDDDCA' (strings of random length and all in caps). After looking around I came across [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/713296/reason-for-excessive-dns-nxdomain-replies-for-domains) which explains it is the DNS anti-spoofing testing. I want to know whether it is completely normal and is performed by google chrome or there is something fishy like DOS attack going on.

Edit: Windows server are also acting as DNS servers and both are present behind the corporate firewall. Currently I am using Splunk Enterprise Security as SIEM tool. Splunk is raising the notable event "**Excessive DNS Failures**"

Comment: This is looking normal. You can capture the packets from a client and confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified that whenever Google chrome browser is launched, it generates series of such random queries (around 6-9) which is forcing the DNS server to return NXDOMAIN response. The link in the question helped me to verify the chrome behavior.